# Connect to old mysql installation using python-mysql,

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I'm trying to connect to database built in into a physical device, and I don't want to change any configuration of this mysql server.

When I try to connect i get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connect3031.py", line 3, in <module>
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='..', database='...', password='...', host='192.168.88.100')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 45, in Connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 366, in __init__
    self.connect(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 411, in connect
    ssl=(ssl_ca, ssl_cert, ssl_key))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 449, in _open_connection
    self._charset)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mysql/connector/protocol.py", line 350, in do_auth
    "Authentication with old (insecure) passwords "\
mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication with old (insecure) passwords is not supported: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-hashing.html
```

Typical response for such problem is, for example, here [mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043247/mysqlnd-cannot-connect-to-mysql-4-1-using-the-old-insecure-authentication), however I don't want to touch this server (apart from selecting data), so updating user is out of question.

Is there any way I can configure client so it accepts these old insecure passwords. I really don't care for security, since it will be accessed via VPN, and all passwords are essentially common knowledge, as they are printed in the manual.

Server in question is (anyways that's what `mysqldump` tells me:

```
Server version       4.1.7-max
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to use an other connector.

[MySQL-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python) seems to support MySQL3.23+.

[mysql-connector-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python) simply can't connect using old authentication.